# Create XML file with python by iterating over lists

Tags: python, xml, moodle

I am trying to get an xml file that looks like this so that I can import it into a moodle gradebook:

```xml
<results>
  <result>
    <student>1</student>
    <assignment>100</assignment>
    <score>0</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>1</student>
    <assignment>101</assignment>
    <score>4</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>1</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>100</assignment>
    <score>0</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>101</assignment>
    <score>4</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
</results>
```

I have tried to write some code in python, and after poring over the documentation, the best I can come up with is:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

students = [1,2]
assignments=[100,101,102]
scores=[0,4,10]
results = ET.Element("results")
result = ET.SubElement(results,"result")
student = ET.SubElement(result,"student")
assignment = ET.SubElement(result,"assignment")
score = ET.SubElement(result,"score")

for s in students:    
    for a in range(len(assignments)):
        student.text = str(s)
        assignment.text = str(assignments[a])
        score.text = str(scores[a])
        results.append(result)
tree = ET.ElementTree(results)
tree.write('test.xml')
```

This almost gives me what I want, but the last entry seems to overwrite all the previous entries as shown:

```xml
<results>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
  <result>
    <student>2</student>
    <assignment>102</assignment>
    <score>10</score>
  </result>
</results>
```

I have tried to find a solution, but it seems that most of the questions address just writing an xml file with distinct elements. What I can't figure out is how to use the same element tag but to assign distinct values to each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Move the lines [Eli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958/eli) suggested into the for loop.
- Remove the line: `results.append(result)` from the for loop. The `SubElement` factory takes as its first argument a parent element
  (as you know) and it *appends* the newly created instance to that
  parent. Therefore you don't need to append it again (you won't get
  any error, but you will get a different set of results than the ones
  you specified).

You loop should then look like:

```
for s in students:    
    for a in range(len(assignments)):

        result = ET.SubElement(results,"result")
        student = ET.SubElement(result,"student")
        assignment = ET.SubElement(result,"assignment")
        score = ET.SubElement(result,"score")

        student.text = str(s)
        assignment.text = str(assignments[a])
        score.text = str(scores[a])
```

Comment: Thanks! That produced the exact results I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move these lines

```
result = ET.SubElement(results,"result")
student = ET.SubElement(result,"student")
assignment = ET.SubElement(result,"assignment")
score = ET.SubElement(result,"score")
```

To inside the `for` loop. Otherwise you're just adding the same `result` over and over again.